# Welcome loader issue in React using onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am implementing welcome loader with React. it is working fine when page is loaded first. but when i refresh the page again the loader is not disappearing onload.
here is the code->

```
function App(){

        const [isLoader, setIsLoader] = useState(false);


        useEffect(() => {
            setIsLoader(true);
            window.addEventListener("load", setLoaderHandle);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener("load", setLoaderHandle);
            }

        }, []);


        const setLoaderHandle = () => {
            const time = setTimeout(() => setIsLoader(false), 1300);
        }


        return (
           <> 
              {isLoader && <Loader />}
           </>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Load Event is called once you added a event listener to that so openning a new tab your load event will  be called  but for your refresh load event is not called so `setLoaderHandle`  is also not called.

You can call the `setLoaderHandle` inside the useEffect to make sure on every component mount it is called.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoader(true);
    window.addEventListener("load", setLoaderHandle);
    setLoaderHandle();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", setLoaderHandle);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: So if i directly put it inside the hook... it will directly call the setLoaderhandle. But i only want it to be called once the page is loaded completely

Comment: the you should set the initial value as true and on page load you set it to false  but on refresh the loader won't come  as on refresh you are still on same page so onload event won't get fired

Comment: it is working,,,, only thing i don't understand is..... event listener and setLoaderHandle is kept together..... so setEventHandler will be called before page load and will make the loader false.

Comment: when you open a new tab that will be the case on subsequent Reload  the onload event won't be called, you can remove eventListner part now as it is irrevelent now

Comment: is there any other way i could get the same welcome loader feel onload and refresh ?

Comment: you can store time returned by SetTimeOut as variable and on ```setLoaderHandle``` 1st clear the timeout and then do a setTimeout to set to False , in that case on initial tab open the  the default setLoaderHandle request is cancelled on Load event and a new request is triggred and on refresh since the load event is not called the default setLoaderHandle request will be triggered